# Easy; can't call a method right before itself in Java?

Tags: java

Im trying to finish up a project for my basic Java course, but I'm running into a weird problem that should be easy to figure out.

http://i.gyazo.com/2016f61886dc314dd44017bbfea94181.png

Why can I not call the ATMMenu method right before it when I can call it all I want in itself?

I think Eclipse is thinking I'm trying to create a new method with the same name, when all Im trying to do is call on it. What am I doing wrong? :/

```
    Client client = new Client(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, phoneNumber, deposit);

ATMMenu(); // error here

void ATMMenu() { // error on this line too

    System.out.println("Select from the following menu options below:");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("[1] Check Balance");
    System.out.println("[2] Withdraw");
    System.out.println("[3] Deposit");
    System.out.println("[4] Show Personal Details");
    System.out.println("[5] Exit");
    System.out.println("============================================");
    System.out.println("Please select your option now:");

    option = sc.nextInt();

    while (exitStatus == 1) {

        if (option == 1) {
            checkBalance();
            ATMMenu();
        }
```

edit: sorry about that.

error: duplicate method. Im not trying to create two methods with the same name, Im trying to call on the method right below it.

Comment: Please don't link to code, post it here.

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited those in.

Comment: Of course error there. Where do you call ATMMenu() from? Seems to not be in any method and if it is, then you're declaring a method inside other method.

Comment: Aren't you mising a final closing bracket `}` ?

Comment: Im calling it from a class, not within a method :) 

Also, that is not the whole code, I didnt post all of it since that would be long. But Im not missing an ending bracket, everything works flawlessy without the "ATMMenu();" line

Comment: And that's the exact problem. You can't call it from the class, there is no such space as "class" where you can call anything.

Comment: You can't just call it in a class - you must declare methods in classes, and then call methods from other methods. The first method you call must be called from the `main` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling ATMMenu(); on line 47 outside of a method declaration. The way you have it written is just as a line of code to execute. If you're just trying to call your ATMMenu() method, you need an entry point to your code - likely a main() method. In this case, for example:

```
public class Client {
    ..
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Client client = new Client(...);
       client.atmMenu(); // camel case convention is lowerCaseFirstLetterOnMethodName
    }
    ..
    void atmMenu() {
        ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call an instance method anywhere in a class declaration. It has to be called in the scope of another method, or in an initializer, or to initialize a field.

Comment: NB: You can call a static method.

Comment: Interesting, I didnt know that! May I ask how to call on variables in other methods as I would need to do that with that change.